# Get info of audio file with his path - Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer

Actually, I'm playing a song with this simple part of code:

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:clickedPath];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];


    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    controller.player = player;
    [player play];
```

What I would like to do is showing the song's info (artist, album name and artwork, etc...) using a custom view showed with contentOverlayView's property of AVPlayerViewController.
I've searched all around here but found nothing that would be useful for my case (either found MPMediaPlayer solution or not working ones).

Coule you help me please ? I'm open to test your suggestions and discuss about it !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youraudiomp3filename" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
NSString *title;
NSString *artist;
NSString *albumName;
UIImageView *imageView;
for (AVMetadataItem *item in metadata) {
    if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        title = (NSString *)[item value];
    }

    if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {
        artist = (NSString *)[item value];
    }

    if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"albumName"]) {
        albumName = (NSString *)[item value];
    }

    if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {
        NSData *data = [(NSDictionary *)[item value] objectForKey:@"data"];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data] ;
        imageView.image = img;
        continue;
    }
}
```

then you can set the asset to the player of your AVPlayerViewController, play and present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this soon ! I'm assuming that the NSString path can be replaced with the full file's path ? I would like to replace it because the tableview is populated dinamically depending on the Document folder content and the song that is played depend on what the user choose !

Comment: Yes, you can use the full file path

Comment: The first " variable are correctly shown in a NSLog for example, but when the time to get album artwork come, the app crash. Here is the crash log : 2016-05-24 12:55:43.654 FileStore[247:6669] -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137e3e290
2016-05-24 12:55:43.656 FileStore[247:6669] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137e3e290'. Do you have an idea why the objectForKey is not recognized for item object ?

Comment: I've tried with NSData *data = [item.value copyWithZone:nil]; The app no more crash but when I try to show the UIImageView, there is nothing inside so I think the img from data is not gotten

Comment: I've resolved the issue, see my answer ! However I will mark your one as the correct one as you've lead me to the correct way ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @L A's help, I've successfully managed to get all the song's info with:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];


        NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:clickedPath];
        NSLog(@"url : %@", url);
        avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];


        AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

        NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
        NSString *songTitle;
        NSString *artist;
        NSString *albumName;
        UIImageView *albumImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];


        for (AVMetadataItem *item in metadata) {

            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {

                songTitle = (NSString *)[item value];
                NSLog(@"song title : %@", songTitle);

            }

            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"albumName"]) {

                albumName = (NSString *)[item value];
                NSLog(@"album name : %@", albumName);

            }

            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artist"]) {

                artist = (NSString *)[item value];
                NSLog(@"song artist : %@", artist);

            }

            if ([[item commonKey] isEqualToString:@"artwork"]) {

                NSData *data = [item dataValue];
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data] ;
                albumImageView.image = img;
                [albumImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
                continue;

            }
        }


        AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        [controller.contentOverlayView addSubview:albumImageView];
        controller.player = avPlayer;
        [avPlayer play];
```